# Different ways to add an app to settings.py

Tags: django

There are two ways to add an app to Django's `settings.py`:

```
'appname.apps.AppnameConfig',
```

and

```
'appname',
```

I know for third-party apps installed through `pip`, it is not possible to use the first method. But what's the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: Both can be used, also for third-party apps. Normally the `__init__.py` will contain a reference to what app config that should be used. If that is the case, you can work with the name of the app; otherwise you need to reference the `AppConfig` to disambiguate between the different app names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be used for third-party apps. The idea is that in order to use an app, you need to load the corresponding `AppConfig`.

Django has a mechanism to determine the `AppConfig` to use. If there is no subclass of `AppConfig` in the `apps.py`, then the default `AppConfig` is used for that application.

If there is a single subclass of `AppConfig`, then it will make use of that `AppConfig`. If there are multiple such subclasses, and one has `default=True`, then that will be the `AppConfig` that is used.

We can also specify a default `AppConfig` in the `__init__.py` of the app module, so then the `__init__.py` looks like:

```
# app_name/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.AppConfigSubclass'
```

These are thus all used to determine the *default* `AppConfig`. It means that if you write the name of the app as an element of the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS), it is used to determine the *default* `AppConfig` to run this.

It is however sometimes necessary to run the application with another subclass of the `AppConfig`. In that case you specify the full qualified name of the `AppConfig`, so then the `INSTALLED_APP` looks like:

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'app_name.apps.OtherAppConfig'
    # …
]

# …
```

So as long as it is clear what the default app is, we can work with the name of the app. From the moment we need another `AppConfig` than the default one, it is necessary to specify that `AppConfig`.